# Material UI style Disappeare on Page Refresh

Tags: next.js, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I am converting my React app into Next app to take advantage of SSR. I am using Material ui 4 for styling.

I have implemented `_app.js` and `_document.js` file as per the Material ui documentation but the problem is when the page is loaded for the first time, material ui styles are not being applied but when I make some changes in my components then only all the styles appear.

I am posting this question only after referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913703/material-ui-breaks-after-refreshing), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797057/material-ui-button-loses-styling-after-page-refresh) answers and other resources on internet

**_app.js**

```
import '@assets/fonts/global.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Layout from "@layout/Layout";
import Footer from "@layout/Footer/Footer";
import Header from "@layout/Header/Header";
//import Sidebar from "@layout/Sidebar/Sidebar";

//Material UI
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import theme from "@helper/theme/theme";
import {ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/styles";

//Redux
import {wrapper} from "@store/store";


function MyApp({Component, pageProps}) {

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
        const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
        if (jssStyles) {
            jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
        }
    }, []);

    return (

        <>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline/>
                <Header/>
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
                <Footer/>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </>
    );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

**_document.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, {Html, Head, Main, NextScript} from 'next/document';
import {ServerStyleSheets} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from "@helper/theme/theme";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {

    render() {

        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main/>
                    <NextScript/>
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {

    console.log('DOC Called');

    // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
        ...initialProps,
        // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
        styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
    };
};
```

*Note: Even after using `_app.js` and `_document.js` file as per the Material ui documentation I'm still getting the following warning in console*

```
next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Prop `className` did not match.
```

Comment: do you used CacheProvider ?

Comment: @H9ee No, I don't.

Comment: this is example code try this : https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_app.js

Comment: The repo you linked is for `MUI 5` and I am using `Material UI 4`.  I have referred [this](https://github.com/geekyshow1/nextmaterialui/tree/master/pages) github repository of a youtuber who has used `Material UI 4` `_app.js` and `_document.js` files from material-ui repo at the time when it was available

Comment: That link is example Material Ui v4 : https://v4.mui.com/getting-started/example-projects/ , i had this your problem in one of  my project , when i use CacheProvider, that be fix, you can try this, maybe it will be fix

Comment: Can you share the code for reference because [in this example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_app.js) `CacheProvider` is imported from `@emotion/react` and `emotionCache` is destructured from `props` but I am not using `emotion`

Comment: This sounds like a hydration issue. Take a look at this https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error from Next.js. It is referring to cases where css-in-js libraries like emotion are used.

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou I have already referred the `Next.js` example for `Material UI` as suggested in the link you provided but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for days here are the things i did:

- Made sure my theme is on src folder
- I used this folder structure and `_document.js` and `_app.js` and `index.js` provided in material [official example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/v4.x/examples/nextjs). Make sure to follow every detail provided in each of these files. they way things are imported, their folder structure, combination of theme and …
- I turned off `SSR` for components such as footer or some other static data that didn't need `SSR` by adding `nossr` wrapper. I had breakpoints in my themes which caused to break `css` in refresh so turning off SSR when not needed made components to fully load on client:

```
import React from 'react';

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const NoSSRWrapper = props => <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>;
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSSRWrapper), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

```
import NoSSRWrapper from '../../components/NoSSRWrapper';
function func() {
  return (
    <NoSSRWrapper>
//your component
   </NoSSRWrapper>
    )
}
```

Also I suggest instead of wrapping your `_app.js` with redux you use  `<Provider store={store}>`
something like this(small details of your _app.js matters)

```
import store from '../utils/store';
  return (
  <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the style mismatch issue? The `reactStrictMode` is turned on by default if using `create-next-app`

According to the following link here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/18018 Material UI v4 is not strict mode compatible so until then you can try disabling reactStrictMode or use Material UI v5.

```
// in next.config.js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false
}
```

Apologies if I misunderstood anything!

Comment: I tried it but still not working